# deque.popleft() vs list.pop(0), performance analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, performance, deque

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543608/deque-popleft-and-list-pop0-is-there-performance-difference), I checked the performance on my laptop.

Surprisingly, I found that `pop(0)` from a `list` is faster than `popleft()` from a `deque` stucture:

```
python -m timeit 'l = range(10000)' 'l.pop(0)'
```

gives:

> 10000 loops, best of 3: **66 usec** per loop

While:

```
python -m timeit 'import collections' 'l = collections.deque(range(10000))' 'l.popleft()'
```

gives:

> 10000 loops, best of 3: **123 usec** per loop

Moreover, I checked the performance on jupyter finding the same outcome:

```
%timeit l = range(10000); l.pop(0)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: **64.7 µs** per loop

```
from collections import deque
%timeit l = deque(range(10000)); l.popleft()
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: **122 µs** per loop

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `timeit` call also times the deque/list *creation*, and creating a `deque` is obviously much slower because of the chaining.

In the command line, you can pass the *setup* to `timeit` using the `-s` option like this:

```
python -m timeit -s"import collections, time; l = collections.deque(range(10000000))" "l.popleft()"
```

Also, since setup is only run once, you get a pop error (empty list) after a whule, since I haven't changed default number of iterations, so I created a large deque to make it up, and got

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0758 usec per loop
```

on the other hand with `list` it's slower:

```
python -m timeit -s "l = list(range(10000000))" "l.pop(0)"
100 loops, best of 3: 9.72 msec per loop
```

I have also coded the bench in a script (more convenient), with a setup (to avoid clocking the setup) and 99999 iterations on a 100000-size list:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(stmt='l.pop(0)',setup='l = list(range(100000))',number=99999))
print(timeit.timeit(setup='import collections; l = collections.deque(range(100000))', stmt='l.popleft()', number=99999))
```

no surprise: `deque` wins:

```
2.442976927292288 for pop in list
0.007311641921253109 for pop in deque
```

note that `l.pop()` for the list runs in `0.011536903686244897` seconds, which is very good when popping the last element, as expected.

Comment: Do you mean that a correct analysis should consider the creation of the deque just once rather than n times?

Comment: @Ale: yes, create it once. Unless you want to measure creation + pop. Edited my post to show a command line approach (did some research in-between)