# How to find values closest to a given value and return the corresponding keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {'bananas':'3', 'apples':'10', 'pears':'9', 'grapes':'2', 'oranges':'21', 'peaches':'12'}
```

I want to create a function that, when the user inputs fruit x, the 2 fruits with the closest count to fruit x are returned.

For example, if the user inputs apples as x, the function would return pears and peaches.

If grapes was entered as x, bananas and pears would be returned.

Algorithmically, this is pretty simple. I'm wondering if there is a pythonic way to make this happen.

Comment: maybe include your proposed algorithm in the question and we can give you tips on how to make it more pythonic

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "conceptually" it is pretty simple. But you still need to come up with an algorithm to do it.

If it will really always be the 2 closest elements, you could have 2 variables holding the closest and second closest matches so far. Then iterate through the dictionary, and for each fruit you find, execute this logic: if closer than first closest, copy first closest to second closest, and copy the new fruit to the first closest. Otherwise, if closer than second closest, copy the new one over the second closest.

If there's a chance this will generalize to the n closest matches, then you could do something like this: create a heapq to hold the n nearest matches. Iterate through the dictionary. At each step, push the (distance, fruit) tuple into the heapq. If the length of the heapq is more than n, pop the largest element (longest distance) off the queue and discard it. In the end, the heapq will hold the n closest items.

Or you could just use a list comprehension to create a list of (distance, fruit) pairs, then sort it, then take the n smallest entries (n=2 in your case).

Another option, based on @RoadRunner's suggestion, would be to create and store a sorted list of (count, fruit) tuples (e.g., `search_list = sorted([(c, f) for (f, c) in my_dict.items()])`. Then use the bisect function from the bisect module to quickly find where (x_count, x) belongs in this list. Then check distances for up to 2 positions forward or backward from there, making a (short) list of (x_count-fruit_count, fruit) pairs for those candidates. Then sort this list and take the first two items.

I'm not giving complete details because this sounds a little like homework, but hopefully this will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple approach using deques.

**Given**

```
import collections as ct


my_dict = {
    "bananas":"3", "apples":"10", "pears":"9",
    "grapes":"2", "oranges":"21", "peaches":"12"
}
```

**Code**

```
def search_neighbors(query, sorted_iterable):
    """Return the nearest neighbors."""    
    # Build data structures
    lookup_idx = {v[0]: i for i, v in enumerate(sorted_iterable)}
    dq = ct.deque(sorted_iterable)

    # Pop searched items from a deque
    idx = lookup_idx[query]
    dq.rotate(-idx)      
    left = dq.pop()
    center = dq.popleft()
    right = dq.popleft()
    if left[-1] > right[-1]:
        # Correction for min/max values
        if center[-1] == min(d.values()):
            left = dq.popleft()
        else:
            right = dq.pop()
    return left, right
```

**Demo**

```
d = {k: int(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

For most cases:

```
search_neighbors("apples", sorted_items)
# (("pears", 9), ("peaches", 12))

search_neighbors("bananas", sorted_items)
# (('grapes', 2), ('pears', 9))

search_neighbors("peaches", sorted_items)
# (('apples', 10), ('oranges', 21))
```

For queries of the min/max values:

```
search_neighbors("grapes", sorted_items)
# (("pears", 9), ("bananas", 3))

search_neighbors("oranges", sorted_items)
# (('peaches', 12), ('apples', 10))
```

---

**Details**

The dictionary converts numeric strings to integers so that it can be sorted.  The sorted keys are indexed in a reversed dictionary for faster lookup.  The sorted items are added to a deque.  After rotating the deque to the position of the queried item, the nearest neighbors are popped (left and right).  If min/max values are detected, i.e. the values of the popped items are out of sequence, the next successive items are popped instead in either direction.  Note: during this correction, variables are overwritten and no longer strictly left and right directions.

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543608/deque-popleft-and-list-pop0-is-there-performance-difference) on the performance of `deque.popleft()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be used,

Your range is quite crazy but I believe adjusting `key-3` and `key+4` will handle your job.

```
def near():
    key = int(my_dict[input("Enter Key:")])
    return [i for i in my_dict if int(my_dict[i]) in range(key-3,key+4)]
```

So now when you run it:

```
>>> near()
Enter Key:apples
['pears', 'peaches', 'apples']
>>>
```

You can remove apples from the list easily but that's left out for you!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def search(x, fruits):
    # get the count of the fruit
    count = fruits[x]

    # get the rest of the elements
    rest = {k: _ for k, _ in fruits.items() if k != x}

    # dictionary that stores fruits count differences
    diff = {_: abs(int(count) - int(v)) for _, v in rest.items()}

    # get the top two closest fruits and store them in a set
    top_two = {x for x, _ in sorted(diff.items(), key = itemgetter(1)) [:2]}

    # return the top two closest
    return [(x, fruits[x]) for x in fruits if x in top_two]
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> my_dict = {'bananas':'3', 'apples':'10', 'pears':'9', 'grapes':'2', 
'oranges':'21', 'peaches':'12'}
>>> search('apples', my_dict)
[('pears', '9'), ('peaches', '12')]
>>> search('bananas', my_dict)
[('pears', '9'), ('grapes', '2')]
>>> search('grapes', my_dict)
[('bananas', '3'), ('pears', '9')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a separate approach using iterators and a third-party tool, [`more_itertools.adajecent`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.adjacent).  This code yields neighbors at a distance 1 or more away from the queried item.

**Code**

```
def search_neighbors(query, sorted_items, distance=1):
    """Yield neighboring items."""
    if query in sorted_items[0] or query in sorted_items[-1]:
        if query in sorted_items[-1]:
            sorted_items = reversed(sorted_items)

        sorted_iter = iter(sorted_items)
        next(sorted_iter)
        for _ in range(distance*2):
            yield next(sorted_iter)
    else:
        pred = lambda x: x[0] == query
        items = (item for bool_, item in mit.adjacent(pred, sorted_items, distance) if bool_)
        for _ in range(distance):
            yield next(items)
        next(items)
        for _ in range(distance):
            yield next(items)

# Pre-build dictionaries
d = {k: int(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

**Demo**

Items are sorted according to their values.  For items inside the list (away from the ends) left and right neighbors are yielded.

```
>>> # Non-Terminal Items
>>> list(search_neighbors("apples", sorted_items))
[("pears", 9), ("peaches", 12)]
>>> list(search_neighbors("bananas", sorted_items))
[('grapes', 2), ('pears', 9)]
>>> list(search_neighbors("peaches", sorted_items))
[('apples', 10), ('oranges', 21)]
```

Items found at the ends of the list are treated differently - consecutive items are yielded, either forward or reversed.

```
>>> # Terminal Items
>>> list(search_neighbors("grapes", sorted_items))
[("pears", 9), ("bananas", 3)]
>>> list(search_neighbors("oranges", sorted_items))
[('peaches', 12), ('apples', 10)]
```

`2n` neighbors can be yielded up to a distance `n` for non-terminals queries on either side and up `2n` for terminal queries.

```
>>> # Distance
>>> n = 2
>>> list(search_neighbors("apples", sorted_items, distance=n))
[('bananas', 3), ('pears', 9), ('peaches', 12), ('oranges', 21)]
>>> list(search_neighbors("grapes", sorted_items, distance=n))
[('bananas', 3), ('pears', 9), ('apples', 10), ('peaches', 12)]
```

The iterator short-circuits if the distance is larger than the sorted iterable.

```
>>> # Early Termination
>>> list(search_neighbors("grapes", sorted_items, distance=10))
[('bananas', 3),
 ('pears', 9),
 ('apples', 10),
 ('peaches', 12),
 ('oranges', 21)]
```