# list.pop() and deque.pop() -- is there a performance difference?

Tags: python

This question is a follow up to this one:
[deque.popleft() and list.pop(0). Is there performance difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543608/deque-popleft-and-list-pop0-is-there-performance-difference)

In Python, I can pop the last item added to a list using `.pop()`. I can also pop the last item using dequeue and `.pop()`.

Is there a performance difference between these two?  Is there a reason or use case that one should be used over the other?

*Edit: Typo.... changed .popright to .pop -- deque's "pop right" is still just .pop -- thanks [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438344/1110324)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, it's called `pop` for both `list` and `deque`, there is no `popright` method on `deque`s.

There is usually no meaningful performance difference between the two; every once in a while, a `pop` on a `deque` will cause a block deallocation (which has fixed overhead, it just makes that particular `pop` a little more costly), and on a `list` it can cause a realloc to shrink the underlying storage (which could end up being `O(n)`, but only a tiny fraction of `pop`s will cause it); asymptotically they're both `O(1)` operations. If your `list` is truly huge, then shrinks a *lot* you might get the occasional performance hiccup when it shrinks the underlying storage, but otherwise you're highly unlikely to notice a difference.

In answer to your question, `deque`s are ever-so-slightly more efficient for use as stacks than `list`s; if you're importing `collections` anyway, and need a stack based structure, using a `deque` will get you a tiny benefit (at least on CPython, can't speak to other implementation). But it's not really worth micro-optimizing here; the cost of importing `collections` in the first place, and the cost of whatever useful code you execute based on this stack, likely dwarfs whatever tiny difference you'll see between `list` and `deque` for `pop`s from the right. A simple `ipython3` microbenchmark:

```
In [24]: %%timeit from collections import deque; s = deque([0] * 10000); onethousandnones = (None,) * 1000; pop = s.pop
    ...: ; push = s.append
    ...: for _ in onethousandnones:
    ...:     pop()
    ...: for _ in onethousandnones:
    ...:     push(0)
    ...:
    ...:
104 µs ± 7.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [25]: %%timeit s = [0] * 10000; onethousandnones = (None,) * 1000; pop = s.pop; push = s.append
    ...: for _ in onethousandnones:
    ...:     pop()
    ...: for _ in onethousandnones:
    ...:     push(0)
    ...:
    ...:
131 µs ± 8.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So for a 1000 pops followed by 1000 pushes onto our stack, the `deque`-based stack  took 30 µs less (~15 ns less per operation). Now admittedly, if I remove the call parentheses to time the base overhead, the base overhead was around 50 µs, so the overhead specifically attributable to the `list` is a significant fraction of the "minimum cost" of the `deque`, but it's still pretty small in the context of a program that is presumably doing something useful, not just pushing and popping to a stack. And **it's pretty stable regardless of size; for a stack that's 10x the size, the cost remains unchanged for both `deque` and `list`**. If the stack was growing and shrinking so much that `list`'s amortized growth was kicking in, it might suffer a little more from the larger reallocations, but it's not normally something to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

`list.pop()` is O(1). It doesn't need to copy anything, it just clears the last element and decrements the length of the list.

Deques are designed to optimize pushing and popping from either end, so both `popleft()` and `popright()` are O(1).

Answer (score 0):

A python deque is implemented as a doubly linked list . This results in pop operations more efficient than lists [O(1)]. However if you want to access elements using their index , lists are faster.

Comment: Technically, `deque`s are a doubly-linked list of *blocks* (each block holding an implementation defined number of elements), so there is a non-uniform cost to `pop` (for block size `n`, `n - 1` pops cost `x`, where `x` is the cost to just return the item and adjust the end of `deque` marker, and `1` pop costs `x+y`, where `y` is the additional cost of freeing the block). In any event, `list.pop()` (with no argument) is amortized `O(1)`, so it's not meaningfully distinct from `deque.pop()` performance overall.