# How do I reorganize a list back with the help of a dict

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 100), ('c', 200), ('d', 300), ('e', 400), ('f', 500)]
list2 = [[0, 200, 400], [100, 300, 500]]
```

`list2` just basically reorganizes the numbers into teams, the 2 sublists.

My `list3` would then be:

```
list3 = [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

So by looking up the values in `list2` in `list1`, what code do I need to produce `list3`?

This is also valid:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0)]
list2 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

It would give:

```
list3 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

So basically `'a'` and `'f'` could have the same value but they can only return once in `list3`

Comment: I would try to come up with a more succinct way of asking the question..

Comment: @MikeQ What's not succinct about it? It seems fine to me.

Comment: Can you post your code for creating `list2` from `list1`? It should follow the same logic, or the question is not clear

Comment: @Sri `list2` is not created from `list1`. I'm not sure what you're confused about though.

Comment: @wjandrea I like it a lot more now, too much ancillary info before.

Comment: Are the first items in the tuples of `list1` expected to be unique through `list1`?

Answer (score 8):

A possibility is to use `collections.defaultdict` with `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
def to_num(a, b):
  d = defaultdict(deque)
  for j, k in a:
     d[k].append(j)
  return [[d[l].popleft() for l in i] for i in b]

list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 100), ('c', 200), ('d', 300), ('e', 400), ('f', 500)]
list2 = [[0, 200, 400], [100, 300, 500]]
print(to_num(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

With your second test case:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0)]
list2 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
print(to_num(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: Why do you use a deque instead of a list? Is it because `deque.popleft()` is faster than `list.pop(0)`?

Comment: @wjandrea `deque.popleft()` is indeed faster than `list.pop(0)`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543608/deque-popleft-and-list-pop0-is-there-performance-difference). Additionally, I think that a "remove from the front" operation best fits the `deque` paradigm.

Answer (score 4):

You can first collect first values of elements of `list1` depending on second element of values of `list1`:

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
byvalue = defaultdict(deque)
for name, value in list1:
    byvalue[value].append(name)
```

then you can collect back the result by processing `list2`

```
list3 = [[byvalue[value].popleft() for value in x]
         for x in list2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea using `pop` to avoid duplicate items:

```
def pop_element(inp_list, search_value): 
    for index, (_, query_value) in enumerate(inp_list): 
        if query_value == search_value: 
            return inp_list.pop(index)[0] 

list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 100), ('c', 200), ('d', 300), ('e', 400), ('f', 500)]
list2 = [[0, 200, 400], [100, 300, 500]]
list3 = [[pop_element(list1, value) for value in inner_list] for inner_list in list2]

# list 3 is [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

It also works on your other example:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0)]   
list2 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]                                                                                                                                
list3 = [[pop_element(list1, value) for value in inner_list] for inner_list in list2]

# list3 is [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

And it conveniently places `None` values when a value from `list2` is not found:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0)]   
list2 = [[0, 0, 11], [0, 'this is a value', 0]]                                                                                                                                
list3 = [[pop_element(list1, value) for value in inner_list] for inner_list in list2]

# list3 is [['a', 'b', None], ['c', None, 'd']]
```

The only caveat is that this method turns `list1` into an empty list, so you might want to do `list1_copy = list1.copy()` and pass that to the list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
In [220]: list3 = []

In [221]: dict1 = dict(list1)

In [225]: for i in list2:
     ...:     l = [] 
     ...:     for j in i: 
     ...:         l.append(list(dict1.keys())[list(dict1.values()).index(j)]) 
     ...:     list3.append(l) 
     ...:     

In [226]: list3
Out[226]: [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lamdba function and generator

```
def find(x):
    " find matching value of x in lst2 " 
    return next(t[0] for t in list1 if t[1]==x)

list3 = [[find(a) for a in sublist] for sublist in list2]

print(list3)
# out: [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

Comment: [Named lambdas are bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381663/4518341). Use a `def` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea--agreed, and understand from [PEP 8](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/assigning_a_lambda_to_a_variable.html) but like the brevity here.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 100), ('c', 200), ('d', 300), ('e', 400), ('f', 500)]

list2 = [[0, 200, 400], [100, 300, 500]]
list3 = []

#Loop through each sublist in list 2
for sublist in list2:
    #creating an inner list which will go in list3
    inner = []
    for el in sublist:
        for (index, (title, label)) in enumerate(list1):
            if label == el:
                inner.append(title)
                #remove the first element that matches the current label
                list1.pop(index)
                break

    list3.append(inner)

print(list3)
```

Output

```
[['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using **collections.OrderedDict**

code:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 100), ('c', 200), ('d', 300), ('e', 400), ('f', 500)]
list2 = [[0, 200, 400], [100, 300, 500]]
list4 = list2[:]
l1_as_dict = OrderedDict(list1)
for key,value in l1_as_dict.items():

    #spread out list,find the first position,then break double-loop
    for i,a_item in enumerate(list2):
        for j,item in enumerate(list2[i]):
            if value == item:
                list4[i][j] = key
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
print(list4)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```