# Level Order Traversal in python, Can we optimise it better?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

```
def levelorder(root):
    if root is None:
        return
    mylist = [] #similar to use of queue
    mylist.append(root)
    while len(mylist) > 0:
        print(mylist[0])
        node = mylist.pop(0) #deque
        if node.left is not None:
            mylist.append(node.left)
        if node.right is not None:
            mylist.append(node.right)
```

*This is the code i've written in python (**something similar to use of queue date structure**) for level order traversal but the problem here if we use mylist.pop(0), it will have time complexity of O(w) where, w is the width of the tree and in worst case if we have n nodes, it can go O(n^2). In C++, both enque and deque operation is O(1), hence we can do level order traversal in O(n) time*.**Can we do it O(n) in python?**

**EDIT: DONE**

Comment: Use a deque. pop will be O(1)

Comment: How to implemet it here, I tried using it but was unable to. Can you please post some relevant resources here?

Comment: Could you add some **tiny** sample data to test the implementation

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do it O(n) in python?

Yes, use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque


def level_order(root):
    if root is None:
        return
    my_list = deque([])
    my_list.append(root)

    while my_list:
        print(my_list[0])
        node = my_list.popleft()
        if node.left is not None:
            my_list.append(node.left)
        if node.right is not None:
            my_list.append(node.right)
```

The computational complexity of [`deque.popleft`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft) is `O(1)` (see [1](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543608/deque-popleft-and-list-pop0-is-there-performance-difference)).

**Overall Complexity**

As the code passes by each node one time and all the operations are `O(1)` then the overall complexity of the traversal is `O(n)` where is `n` is the cardinality of the set of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simplified linear generator function:

```
def levelorder(root):
    if root:
        row = [root]
        while row:
            yield from row
            row = [c for n in row for c in (n.left, n.right) if c]
```

This can be easily turned into a `list`:

```
x = [*levelorder(some_root)]
```

Or implemented to return a list:

```
def levelorder(root): 
    result = []
    if root:
        row = [root]
        while row:
            result.extend(row)
            row = [c for n in row for c in (n.left, n.right) if c]
    return result
```