# how to update class attribute value from method

Tags: python, class, binary-tree, return-value

I am trying to implement a Binary Tree using a queue. I am having an issue to set a new value for self.root who is initially set in class BinaryTree as None using the method InsertNode(self,data). I try to return self.root with it's new value but the value remains the same (None) Any Idea?

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def InsertNode(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        newNode = newNode.data

        print('self.root =', self.root)
        print('new node', newNode)

        if self.root == None:
            self.root = newNode

            print('self.root =', self.root)

        else:
            print('else won')
            queue = []
            # print(queue)
            queue.append(self.root)
            while True:
                node = queue.pop(0)
                if node.left != None and node.right != None:
                    queue.append(node.left)
                    queue.append(node.right)
                else:
                    if node.left == None:
                        node.left = newNode
                        queue.append(node.left)
                    else:
                        if node.right == None:
                            node.right = newNode
                            queue.append(node.right)
                break
        return self.root
```

Comment: So, you really must provide a [mcve]. But in any case, glancing at what you have, `newNode = newNode.data` seems wrong. The node you created is now gone, and you simply have `newNode = data`, AFAIKT

Comment: Is this a binary search tree? Where do you want to insert the key?

Comment: @funnydman i am just trying to construct a simple binary tree. This is how i would insert elements
BinaryTree().InsertNode(2)
BinaryTree().InsertNode(4)
BinaryTree().InsertNode(6)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did this because otherwise when I try to print(newNode) it returns the location.  Like this:
new node <__main__.Node object at 0x00000241A306AFE0>                                                and it doesn't seem to help me solve the problem I am facing..

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Right after creating a new node and assigning its reference to `newNode`, your code assigns the *data* of that node to `newNode`. At that point you lose the reference to your node, and it is forever lost. Moreover, while `self.root` is supposed to be node reference, you then continue to assign the *data* value to `self.root`. In short, don't do `newNode = newNode.data`
- The `while` loop can only make one iteration, because it has an unconditional `break`. That break should be conditional: it should be indented one level more so it is placed in the `else` block.

With those two fixes, your code will work (provided the other code you have, like for `class Node` is error-free).

Not a problem, but you should also look at these points:

- At the place where you have `if node.right == None`, this condition is always going to be true, given that it was already known that not both `node.left` and `node.right` are `None`, and also that `node.left` is `None`. So the only remaining possibility for `node.right` is that it is `None`.
- Once you have assigned `newNode` to where it belongs, there is no need any more to append to the queue.
- When using a list as a FIFO queue, it [is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543608/deque-popleft-and-list-pop0-is-there-performance-difference) to use a deque and its `popleft` method.
- In Python, names of methods are commonly written with a first lowercase letter. Either name your method `insertNode` or why not just `insert`?
- As `node.left` is a node reference or `None`, you can just test for `node.left` instead of `node.left != None`. Similarly for `node.right`
- Instead of testing for the end-condition inside the `while True` loop, you could change the order of your code a bit and make it a `while node.left and node.right` loop. Then the assignment of `newNode` to the right attribute can happen after the loop has finished.
- The insert method does not need to return the root node. The reference of the root node is maintained in an attribute of the instance. The outside caller should in fact have no need to ever access node references. I would suggest *not* to return the root node.

Here is the resulting code. I added `__repr__` implementations so the tree can be printed with some basic indentation format:

```
from collections import deque

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = self.right = None

    def __repr__(self, tab=""):
        return ((self.right.__repr__("  " + tab) if self.right else "")
              + tab + repr(self.data) + "\n"
              + (self.left.__repr__("  " + tab) if self.left else ""))
        
       
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)

        node = self.root
        if not node:
            self.root = newNode
        else:
            queue = deque()
            while node.left and node.right:
                queue.append(node.left)
                queue.append(node.right)
                node = queue.popleft()
            if node.left:
                node.right = newNode
            else:
                node.left = newNode

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.root).rstrip() if self.root else "<Empty>"

# Example run
tree = BinaryTree()
print(tree)
for i in range(1, 13):
    tree.insert(i)
print(tree)
```